# Publishing content by referencing my Umbraco website DLL in another project

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

I am currently investigating ways to publish content to an Umbraco website by using a WCF Web Service.

In my Umbraco project, `MyWebsite`, I have added the following method in a utility class:

```
public static void ContentCreateTest()
{
    ContentService cService = new ContentService();

    var content = cService.CreateContent("Test Item", 1000, "ContentTypeAlias", 0);

    content.SetValue("property1", "Value 1");
    content.SetValue("property2", "Value 2");

    cService.SaveAndPublishWithStatus(content);
}
```

I have added a reference to my WCF project, and can call the function.

However, I receive the following error:

```
Could not load the Umbraco.Core.Configuration.UmbracoSettings.IUmbracoSettingsSection from config file, ensure the web.config and umbracoSettings.config files are formatted correctly

Server stack trace: 
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

This seems to be caused by the WCF service being unable to connect to my Umbraco website.

What would be the best way to create Umbraco content from another project/solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the REST API, I think. http://24days.in/umbraco/2015/umbraco-rest-api/ :-)

Comment: Thanks for the link - I'm running on 7.2.0 at the moment, so I can't use the REST API. I will be looking into using a web API controller though.